# Using FilesMatch to increase security

Tags: apache-2.2

I've been experimenting with the FilesMatch Directive. During my first attempt, I discovered that my default rules (rulesets 1 & 2) didn't allow me to access `www.test.com/` but did allow me to access `www.test.com/index.php`

I presumed this was because the file `"/"` hit ruleset 1 but not ruleset 2 and so got blocked. I therefore put ruleset 3 in place and everything seems to be working now. I just wanted to ask  if anyone had any advice on implementing this directive, and whether or not I've gone about it the correct way?

```
#Ruleset1
<FilesMatch "^.*$">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

#Ruleset2
<FilesMatch "^.*\.(css|html?|js|pdf|txt|xml|xsl|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|php?)$">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

#Ruleset3
<FilesMatch "">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

This likely isn't working as you're intending.

Your last match effectively overrides the other rules and allows all requests; `""` will always match everything (as will your first section, `"^.*$"`).

Just using `<FilesMatch>` seems like the wrong approach for what you're going for, but can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

***Edit:***

Something like this should function for both cases:

```
<Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Location>
<LocationMatch "(/|\.css|\.html?|\.js|\.pdf|\.txt|\.xml|\.xsl|\.gif|\.ico|jpe?g|\.png|\.php)$">
    Allow from all
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: I'm trying to put in place some CIS guidelines. Namely these ones: 

1.5.11 Restrict File Extensions (Level 2, Scorable)

Description:
Restrict access to inappropriate file extensions that are not expected to be a legitimate part of web sites using the FileMatch directive.

They work in part, but the also block a site when a user accesses www.test.com/ because the "/" doesn't match a rule in the whitelist.

Comment: @leftcase Edited answer with a config that should fit your needs.