# How to keep the default document working while blocking all files except some on Apache2 webserver?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

On my webserver I would like to block all files except some reasonable exceptions.
I have following Filesmatch directive which is doing it's work:

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!\.txt|\.htm|\.html|\.css|\.php|\.js|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.ico|\.svg|\.eot|\.ttf|\.woff|\.otf)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>
```

Note this FilesMatch uses a negative lookbehind regular expression: see http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html. It will block all files except those having an extension as stated.

This results also in an 403 Forbidden for the directory default document (index.html). 
This is not what I want. Can someone help? How does the default document lookup work? Is there another solution to blocking all except some? I looked in Apache2's error log with LogLevel debug, but the only message is "client denied by server configuration" when asking for a default document. 
(Explicitly asking for the index.html works)

Edit: there is a solution to this by using the Location directive. 
See [Using FilesMatch to increase security](https://serverfault.com/questions/402750/using-filesmatch-to-increase-security)
So my problem is solved, but I still would like to know why it does not work with FilesMatch.

Comment: Why do you expect `.html` not to block `index.html` ?

Comment: Why do you have files in that directory, if you don't want people to be able to get them??

Comment: I added some info: the filesmatch directive here is not blocking files ending on .html. And the intention is indeed to show the files with extensions specified, nothing else.